# Performance difference in find command

Tags: shell

Is there any performance difference in the below shell commands:

```
find . -type f -empty -exec rm '{}' \;
find . -type f -empty -exec sh -c "/bin/rm {}" \;
```

Comment: If you are using gnu find it has an action -delete. `find . -type f -empty -delete`.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd command is going to be slower since it will spawn a sub shell for each entry found by find command.

However at the same time 2nd command will be more flexible in nature if you want to do some variable assignment etc like this:

```
find . -type f -empty -exec sh -c "x=1; /bin/rm {}" \;
```